# list of variables in Pandas Python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

hi I would like to loop into the values of a list in a Pandas dataframe structure:

is it possible?

```
#for a single variable
print(df["var1"].value_counts(normalize = True))

my_list=["var1","var2","var3"]

#instead would like to do something like this:

for i in my_list:
   print(df[i].value_counts(normalize = True))
```

Comment: You basically want `value_counts` for these columns: `["var1","var2","var3"]`?

Answer (score 2):

There are built in tools to help.

```
my_list = ["var1", "var2", "var3"]

# j is the column header
# col is the column series
for j, col in df[my_list].iteritems():
    print col.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: thanks but this method loops into all the columns of the dataframe, instead I would like to loop into 3 variables, or I'm missing something?

Comment: no, I was missing something.  updating post... updated

Comment: by the way.  Your solution is perfectly acceptable.  My answer is just an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `apply`, but it's still a loop behind the scenes:

```
df[my_list].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)
```

If all you want to do is print, then use a `lambda` function:

```
df[my_list].apply(lambda col: print(pd.Series.value_counts(col, normalize=True)))
```

Comment: thanks but this method loops into all the columns of the dataframe, instead I would like to loop into 3 variables, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry @progster I misread your question. Why are you unhappy with your code then?

Comment: my bad, I was not perfectly clear with my question. I was wondering if there was any "pandas" more specific trick

Comment: @progster I have edited my answer. It is a bit more 'panda-ic', but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `.apply()` with `lambda`.

```
df[["var1","var2","var3"]].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize = True))
```

Comment: Actually you don't need a `lambda` function: you can pass `normalize=True` as a keyword argument in `apply` directly. See my answer ;)

Comment: @IanS Oh, yeah. I didn't see your answer before.